# Taking screenshot in WP7 Emulator does not refelct the current screen

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

When taking screenshot of WP7 Emulator the current screen that is being displayed in the emulator does not get reflected in screenshot, instead the screen viewed in emulator few minutes before (which is not the current screen) gets reflected.
Even performing refresh is not helping to capture the screenshot of current screen

I want to capture the screenshot of current screen being viewed in emulator. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Does it have to be programmatically taken? You can use the `Snip` tool described at the bottom of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442300%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Windows Phone Emulator, why not just use the built in Screenshot capture feature?

Just move the mouse above the Emulator to show the side menu on the right, then click the bottom "»" option and click on Screenshot tab.

Answer (score 0):

What is the tool that u r using to take a scree shot?? I always use snipping tool and i have never had any problem with the screen shots i have obtained. I suggest you to use **snipping tool** to take wp7 screen shots.

Comment: I used the following code to take screen shot by providing required co-ordinates of WP7 emulator from which the picture has to be taken.
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(capturedImageFromX, capturedImageFromY, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
The screenshot obtained reflects the screen viewed few seconds before and does not capture the current screen being viewed in emulator

Comment: Go with snipping tool i would say thats the best tool to take snapshots from emulator.

Comment: WP7 Mango SDK came with in-build screenshot taker. Pedro Lamas nailed it right.